# How to populate a cell with values from another worksheet but increment cell address by 3?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I know how to populate a cell with values from another worksheet. But how do I skip to the 3rd cell?

Here's what I am trying to do:

```
A1 ='2nd Worksheet'!C4
A2 ='2nd Worksheet'!C7
A3 ='2nd Worksheet'!C10
A4 ='2nd Worksheet'!C13
A5 ='2nd Worksheet'!C16
A6 ='2nd Worksheet'!C19
A7 ='2nd Worksheet'!C22
and so on...
```

without having to manually type in `'2nd Worksheet'!Cxx` incrementing by 3 each time.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the following formula in the A1 cell and drag down:

> =OFFSET(Sheet2!$C$4,3*ROW()-3,0)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of variations:

- `A1` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C$1, 3*ROW(), 0)`
  This references the `C1` cell on `2nd Worksheet`
  and then moves down three rows × the current row number. 
  So, when you drag/fill this down, you’ll get

  - `A1` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C$1, 3, 0)` → `'2nd Worksheet'!C4`
  - `A2` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C$1, 6, 0)` → `'2nd Worksheet'!C7`
  - `A3` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C$1, 9, 0)` → `'2nd Worksheet'!C10`

  You need to specify the `$` in `C$1` to make it an absolute row reference;
  otherwise, when you drag/fill this down, you’ll get

  - `A1` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C1, 3, 0)` → `'2nd Worksheet'!C4`
  - `A2` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C2, 6, 0)` → `'2nd Worksheet'!C8`
  - `A3` → `=OFFSET('2nd Worksheet'!C3, 9, 0)` → `'2nd Worksheet'!C12`

  (because the row number auto-increments). 
  You can say `$C$1` if you want; that won’t make a difference
  (unless you start moving or copying between columns).
- `A1` → `=INDIRECT("'2nd Worksheet'!C" & 3*ROW()+1)`
  This simply constructs the strings that you showed in your question,
  and then uses the `INDIRECT()` function to de-reference those strings
  (i.e., to treat them as cell addresses
  and retrieve the contents of the identified cells).